# Как отменить откат изменений (восстановить потерянный коммит)?

Tags: git, git-revert, git-reset, git-checkout

Вопрос: Есть ли способ в git отменить откат, т.е восстановить состояние, не закоммиченное в git`е ?

Около месяца назад я создал коммит и сегодня я создал коммит( как я думал ), но коммит, как оказалось позже, не создался( моя вина ). Затем, спустя час, я решил произвести откат к последнему коммиту, но так как сегодня во время его создания произошла ошибка, я откатился к коммиту месячной давности.

Comment: Если данные были закоммичены, то к ним можно восстановиться. Если данные не были закоммичены, то скорее всего все утеряно.

Да, коммитить раз в месяц - это странно. git приветствует частые коммиты. Если перестарались и сделали много мелких коммитов - их можно объединить.

Comment: Ясно, что ж, спасибо. Коммит был сделан спустя месяц потому, что месяц к проекту никто не прикасался, а спустя месяц работа возобновилась. Выходит, GIT может превращаться из удобного инструмента в опасный.

Comment: Если данные были закоммичены, то пусть хоть десять откатов назад сделаете, восстановиться можно. 

btw, изучите возможности "[кармана](http://evasive.ru/articles/git_kung-fu.html)" - `git stash` спрятать в карман, `git stash pop` - достать. Карман стековый (можно много запихать). Очень полезный инструмент, если планируете использовать "страшные неизвестные операции".

Comment: если файлы добавлялись в индекс (staging area), то для них будут созданы `blob` объекты в репозитории, и соответственно, можно вытащить содержимое в незаисимости был сделан коммит или нет

Answer (score 8):

Все что попадает в репозиторий не удаляется сразу, т.е. если даже ты удалил ветку, изменил коммит и т.д. есть возможность вернуться к предыдущей версии.
Если же изменения были только в рабочей копии, а потом они "потерялись", то тут уж ничем не поможешь :(.

Ты можешь посмотреть в логе `git reflog` историю изменения `HEAD`,еще можно перечислить все недостижимые объекты `git fsck --unreachable`. Может это поможет.

Если ты добавлял файлы в индекс, но не закомитил их то по выводу `git fsck --unreachable` можно будет найти эти файлы. Содержимое файлов хранится в `blob` объектах. В объектах типа `tree` хранятся коллекции `blob` объектов. Увы не знаю создается ли `tree` объект при добавлении файлов в индекс, но если создается то все что нужно это найти недостижимый `tree` объект с нужными файлами.

Для отображения содержимого объекта: `git cat-file -p <hash>`

Comment: Спасибо, @misha-nesterenko, полезная информация)

Comment: Полезно для этих blob посмотреть сначала дату их создания, мне помогла следующая команда:   `ls -l -t $(git fsck --unreachable | grep blob | sed 's/.* .* //; s|\(..\)|.git/objects/\1/|')`