# git: как "нейтрализовать" коммит?

Tags: git, git-commit

Есть бажный коммит, после него еще несколько коммитов, которые пока нельзя деплоить. Необходимо как-то выкинуть изменения этого коммита из проекта, затем развернуться из следующего перед ним коммита, а потом продолжить работу с последнего коммита, но исключая изменения бажного. Дайте, пожалуйста, последовательность действий.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> затем развернуться из следующего перед ним коммита

Подробная информация в вопросе [Как вернуться (откатиться) к более раннему коммиту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472). Кратко - когда всё почините, сможете просто перейти в нужный коммит или даже новую ветку создать в нём.

> выкинуть изменения этого коммита из проекта,

Про это будет весь ответ дальше.

## Самый важный вопрос:

Успели ли вы запушить эту ветку на удалённый репозиторий? Возможно ли, что другой разработчик уже получил с удаленного репозитория коммит B или один из последующих и продолжает работать над ним. Если ответ - да, то в общем случае желательно `revert`, но не rebase, cherry-pick и прочее, что переписывает историю Git, так как это создает [большие проблемы с интеграцией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/429512/181472).

Поскольку вам нужно развернуться из C, не содержащего изменений из B, то почти наверняка историю переписывать придётся. В таком случае предупредите коллег заранее. Им придётся аналогичным образом ребейзить свои изменения, например с коммита `D` на `D'`.

Обозначим начальную ситуацию на следующей схеме:

```
A - B - C - D 
            ↑
          branchname
          (HEAD)
```

`A`, `B`, `C`, `D` — коммиты в ветке `branchname`.  `B` - "плохой коммит", его нам нужно удалить. Коммит `C` нужно задеплоить.
`(HEAD)` — местоположение указателя HEAD.
`↑` обозначает коммит, на который указывает определенная ветка или указатель.

## Вариант 1 - через `rebase -i`

- Плюс - меньше мусора в истории. И можно гордиться, что освоил rebase.
- Плюс - позволяет развернуться из С, не содержащего изменений из B.
- Минус - переписывает историю, опасно при командной работе.

### Команды:

```
git checkout branchname
git rebase -i A
git checkout -b deployme C'
```

В качестве A мы указываем коммит сразу перед тем, который будем исключать. При этом A останется на месте. Откроется редактор, в нём будут коммиты в обратном порядке. Меняем `pick` на `drop`, обозначая что мы хотим выкинуть этот коммит.

```
drop 323d4e6 comment for B
pick 31da2b9 comment for C
pick 24d420c comment for D

# Rebase c8893f9..24d420c onto c8893f9 (3 command(s))
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

### Результат

```
A - C' - D' 
         ↑
       branchname
       (HEAD)
    ↑
  deployme
  (HEAD)
```

У новых коммитов теперь другой предок, поэтому это - другие, новые коммиты (хотя содержимое то же за вычетом B). Новая ветка deployme смотрит на коммит `C'`.

## Вариант 2 - через `revert`

- Плюс - не переписывает историю и безопасен при командной работе. Проще чем rebase.
- Минус - ошибочный коммит останется в истории. Плохо, если там информация, которую нельзя показывать или код, который стыдно публиковать. :)
- Минус - коммит `C` по-прежнему будет содержать изменения от `B`.

### Команды:

```
git checkout branchname
git revert B
```

### Результат:

```
A - B - C - D - xB
                ↑
              branchname
              (HEAD)
```

Новый коммит `xB` содержит изменения, которые отменяют изменения коммита `B`. Однако у нас есть проблема: коммит `C` по-прежнему содержит изменения от `B`.

Немного подробнее о `revert`:

- [Документация](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)
- [тут, пятый пункт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431521/181472).

## В дополнение:

- Если в процессе ошибётесь или протеряете не тот коммит: [Как отменить откат изменений (восстановить потерянный коммит)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/232455/181472)
- Заодно, при желании, можно что-нибудь сделать и с другими коммитами: [Как разделить/склеить старый комит?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416761/181472).

Comment: Спасибо. Решил попробовать rebase. Но что-то пошло не так: выпало Could not apply (....последний коммит....), я выполнил git rebase --skip и в итоге - последние коммиты пропали. Остался только коммит A

Comment: @Mik там есть инструкция по восстановлению. У вас был конфликт слияния, его надо вручную было разрешить. Теперь git reflog, смотрите куда восстановиться.

Comment: Просто сделал reset --hard к последнему коммиту, и все восстановилось. В итоге коммит было решено не удалять, так как баг легко исправил через ветвление. Но, тем не менее, Ваш ответ мегаполезен и наверняка пригодится в будущем. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Создать ветку из нужного вам коммита и продолжить работу в этой ветке.

```
git checkout -b <имя ветки> <номер коммита>
```

Затем замержить в эту ветку нужные вам коммиты.

```
git cherry-pick <номер коммита>
```

Answer (score 3):

Коммит, удаляющий изменения, сохраненные нежелательным коммитом

```
git revert HEAD
```

Удаление коммита из ветки

```
git reset --hard <tag or hash>
```

Comment: `git reset --hard` не поможет выдернуть из ветки один коммит.

Comment: Однако пригодился для отката после неудачных rebase

Answer (score 3):

`git revert` - создаёт откатывающий коммит, см. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

`git cherry-pick` - позволяет в другом бранче создать Новый коммит с изменениями указанного коммита https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Теоретически этого сочетания должно быть достаточно

Comment: Спасибо, вот и познакомился с этой командой на практике =)