# Как правильно сделать откат git?

Tags: git, веб-программирование, github

Есть 2 ветки, которые, пока что, не должны пересекаться. 1 ветка `last-anketa`, 2 ветка `res-design`. По глупости сделал `merge` `res-design` в 'last-anketa'. В итоге продолжил работу в `last-anketa`, не уделяя особого внимания ошибке, естественно делая коммиты внутри этой ветки. Вообщем нужно перенести комиты из `last-anketa` в новую ветку

Comment: то есть, коммиты после мержда веток 1 и 2 нужно перенести с ветки 1 в ветку 2 и при этом удалить мердж?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509718/178576

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте создать новую ветку из коммита до `"merge res-design"` и использовать [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) для портирования нужных коммитов в новую ветку.

---

Пример ситуации и один из вариантов решения:
[image: Ситуация]

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
 * 7205a26 (last-anketa) Забываем про дизайн и работаем с anketa.html
 * 38e06de Продолжаем работать с anketa.html
 *   cd1f858 Присоединяем res-design к 'last-anketa' при помощи 'git merge res-design'
 |\
 | * 072aeaf (res-design) Работаем с design.css
 | * 2621b85 Создаём новый design.css и встраваем в anketa.html
 * | 5435c8d Продолжаем работу с anketa.html
 |/
 * aaf56c7 Работаем с anketa.html
 * be7ff57 Создаём anketa.html
```

Я использую `git log --oneline --decorate --graph` для просмотра лога. В данной ситуации мы имеем 2 ветки **last-anketa**, которая является основной и **res-design**, который вливается в last-anketa в середине.

Прежде всего создаём новую ветку на базе третьего коммита(5435c8d) (являвшегося последним коммитом в ветке **last-anketa**, прежде чем произошло слияние с веткой **res-design**.

`git checkout`*{номер коммита}*`-b`*{название новой ветки}*

```
 git checkout 5435c8d -b last-anketa-v2
  Switched to a new branch 'last-anketa-v2'
```

Теперь при помощи `git cherry-pick`*{номер коммита}* портируем нужные нам верхние коммиты (38e06de и 7205a26) в новую ветку.

```
git cherry-pick 38e06de
 [last-anketa-v2 5498247] Продолжаем работать с anketa.html
   Date: Thu Oct 27 15:02:51 2016 +0200
   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

git cherry-pick 7205a26
 [last-anketa-v2 9d1282e] Забываем про дизайн и работаем с anketa.html
  Date: Thu Oct 27 15:03:30 2016 +0200
  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Разрешённая ситуация:
[image: git log и git branch -v]

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
 * 9d1282e (last-anketa-v2) Забываем про дизайн и работаем с anketa.html
 * 5498247 Продолжаем работать с anketa.html
 * 5435c8d Продолжаем работу с anketa.html
 * aaf56c7 Работаем с anketa.html
 * be7ff57 Создаём anketa.html
```

И теперь мы имеем чистую паралельную ветку **last-anketa-v2** с нужными изменениями.

При портировании коммитов могут возникнуть конфликты:

```
git cherry-pick 38e06de
 error: could not apply 38e06de... Продолжаем работать с anketa.html
 hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
 hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
 hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

В этом случае нужно:

1. проверить конфликтующие файлы
2. разрешить конфликт
3. вручную создать коммит

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/509652/225489